# Is it a good approach or best practice to use jQuery in angular to handle events or all other stuff?

Tags: jquery, angular

I just want to handle some kind of events and many other stuff in angular. So can I use jQuery in angular because I feel comfort to work in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely discouraged. Mixing up two different libraries in codebase will cause conflicts and considerably affects the performance of the application. Also it will be a nightmare for debugging and maintaining the application, particularly when it grows in its size.

Angular has its own techniques for DOM manipulation, events, and everything that you would expect from a similar framework. If you decided to use Angular framework for your application, just go with the functionalities provided by Angular to accomplish your needs.  It is recommended to use Jquery only if one or more of your 3rd party angular library has a dependency against it. Otherwise you even do not need to include Jquery in your application.